# Spring component scan annotation and meta data

Tags: java, spring

I'm actually studying spring application, more particularly the `ComponentScan` annotation that scans java packages to find some classes annotated with `@Component`.

I was wondering if the Spring *ComponentScan* annotation stores the related components found in other packages inside of the meta-datas of the Main Class (where I have the static void main method?)

Is this the only place where the framework stores these informations?

Comment: What do you mean by *"other packages inside of the meta-datas of the Main Class"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.package" />`

tells spring that it should look on `com.mycompany.package` and find classes annotated with the following (not only `@Component` ):

```
@Controller 
@Repository
@Service
@Component
```

Then [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) will register these classes with the bean factory.

> the Spring IoC container consumes a form of configuration metadata; this  configuration metadata represents how you as an application developer tell the Spring container to instantiate, configure, and assemble the objects in your application.

Configuration metada are either an `xml` Configuration or java classes annotated with `@Configuration` that's where spring stores config informations.